# UISplitViewController makes gray frame on first interaction

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

My problem is demonstrated in this gif:

[image]

As you can see in the first frames, i get a gray box on my first interaction. The background view is red just to check if it was loaded.

My storyboard is set up like this: 
[image]

The only modifications I've made in code is this in the SplitViewController class:

```
class SplitViewController: UISplitViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {
var collapseDetailViewController = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.preferredDisplayMode = .PrimaryOverlay

}

func splitViewController(splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondaryViewController secondaryViewController: UIViewController, ontoPrimaryViewController primaryViewController: UIViewController) -> Bool{
    return collapseDetailViewController
}

}
```

and this in my master tableview

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    (splitViewController as! SplitViewController).collapseDetailViewController = false
}
```

This is because I want the sidebar to show up when the user launches my app. Have anyone experienced this weird error before, and does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've attempted to duplicate, but did not get the gray box upon loading. Instead, it worked as you had intended -- the sidebar loading upon app launch.

I found some similar questions that might provide you with some insight:

- [Hide gray box in UiSplitView when animating to PrimaryHidden from
  PrimaryOverlay...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167266/hide-gray-box-in-uisplitview-when-animating-to-primaryhidden-from-primaryoverlay)
- [Achieve a Uniform UIBlurEffect in the Primary
  View of a UISplitView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26164982/achieve-a-uniform-uiblureffect-in-the-primary-view-of-a-uisplitview)

Comment: I have no idea how I fixed it, but i screwed around and now it works. Go figure.